# How can i validate an email address and password is correct in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am trying to send emails using Yahoo or Gmail. Prior to that i want to check if the username and password combination of the email address i am using to send mails is ok and then send the email.
How can i achieve such a thing in Asp.net/C#?
Is  there a way to find about the status of the sent email ? (delivered or failed?)

Comment: Which email and pwd combination ??  Is it of the email ID you are using to send mails

Comment: Send mail through your id or through others?

Comment: @RajeevKumar: Yes the email address i am trying to send the email with. 
And also is the a way to know the status of the sent email?

Comment: You can simply handle Try/Catch Statement. It USerid/Pwd combination fails. You get to know that something went wrong and check it in catch block. If everything goes right that means mail is sent succesfully

Comment: Actually i am going to separate sending and validating process .If i use that approach and the email address and password is ok, the smtp clients send method would send the email address! i dont want that to happen unless i am using a dummy email for test this. is there any other solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SmtpClient does not offer functions for testing credentials, e.g. just logging in without sending. So the .Net onboard way would be, as previously suggested, to Try/Catch your sending attempt.

If you insist on checking the credentials first, you'd have to implement the SMTP protocol, or parts of it, on your own, using .Net.Sockets.TcpClient. That way you could log on to the SMTP without sending anything.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to receive a so called NDR ([Non-Delivery Report/Receipt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_delivery_report)), but since that is an email sent back to your designated bounce address, you would have to build an application to read those reports as a background process or similar. There is no guarantee that you will get an NDR.

I don't really see the point of checking username/password prior to sending. You would add error handling anyways, so it either fails or succeeds.